# How to close QConsoleApplication not from main

Tags: c++, qt

How can I close an application when I have an object created inside the `main` method, where the main thread is, but the `exit` method I want to call is within the class of the created object.

I used these but it doesn't work:

```
qApp->exit(0);
QApplication::exit(0);
```

My application is debugged on linux, using gdb. I want to kill all inferiors... stop application.

Comment: what do you mean does not work? what inferiors? does it work when not running in the debugger?

Comment: no, when running from device it doesnt close either

Comment: @Hayt but sure I can interupt it with ctrl+z

Comment: Thank you, : exit(EXIT_FAILURE); solved my problem